# Conversion from flash to android tablet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, android-tabs, smartfoxserver

I have a virtual world (user login, create avatar, walk around and play games) running on web with flash/as3 as client side and smartfox2X as server. I have plan to get the whole system into android tablets.

My question is How do I achieve this? or what is the best way to convert the same to run on tabs.. Will the just changing in publish settings from flash player 11 to Air for android work ???

Answer (score 0):

> Will the just changing in publish settings from flash player 11 to Air
>   for android work ???

Yes, this will work to some extends. You will not be able to run native code or to use native acceleration.

You can take a look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org) and [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/), which allows you to compile *"flash"* as Android native app.